# Problem with date in Python

Tags: python

I'm developing a web application and would like to display user's current date basing on his timezone. Here is my code:

```
userTimezone = -5 #EAST is positive, WEST negative 
utcTimestamp = time.mktime(time.gmtime())
userDate = time.gmtime(utcTimestamp+userTimezone*60*60)
```

I think the problem is with gmtime() since it does some conversions automatically. If I could, I would replace gmtime with function which doesn't convert anything, but haven't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably looking for `time.localtime(seconds)`. gmtime always returns utc time.

Comment: It should work properly, but when I print time.gmtime() and userDate from my script the difference between these 2 dates is 6 hours, not 5. Also time.altzone on my computer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set `time.timezone` to the user's timezone, then display it using localtime().